# Non-hermitian physics

Tags: condensed-matter

Recently, I am working on PT symmetric non-hermitian lattices. Can anyone explain why non-hermitian term appears in a system? Particularly, what is the meaning of 'loss and gain' in a system?

Comment: Still looking for reply?